Closed form expression for sum with Hermite polynomial and its derivative.
Can someone help find closed-form expression for the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}(x)H'_{2n}(y)}{2^{2n}(2n)!\sqrt{2n+1}}= ?$$
where $H'_{n}(x)$ denotes the derivative of $H_n(x)$ with respect to x. The sum is similar to the well-known summation formula:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!} = \sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}\delta(x-y).$$
except there is a factor of $\sqrt{2n+1}$ and a derivative of the Hermite polynomial in the numerator instead of the polynomial itself.

Just a random thought: if you take the (distributional...) derivative of the well-known formula (Mehler's?), that might give something related to your sum-of-interest...

It can be expressed by integral:$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+2 \sqrt{1+t} x y+y^2}{t}} \left(\left(-1+e^{\frac{4 \sqrt{1+t} x y}{t}}\right) \sqrt{1+t} x-\left(1+e^{\frac{4 \sqrt{1+t} x y}{t}}\right) y\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }
t^{3/2} (1+t) \sqrt{\log (1+t)}} , dt$$  a closed form solution probably no.
